# Numbering a reworded theorem

Tags: numbering, theorems

When using LaTeX for numbered theorems (or other numbered environments for that matter), if you have a theorem, and then you want to give a reformulation of the theorem, is there anyway to get LaTeX to number your first theorem, say Theorem 5, and your reformulation as say Theorem 5'?

To obtain numbered theorems, I am not using any package, just using the command

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

in my preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one-off use, perhaps the simplest is to say

```
\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}% so next theorem will be 5 again then
\begingroup% local redefinition of theorem counter printing
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{theorem}'}
\begin{theorem}...
\end{theorem}
\endgroup
```

Or for example wrap it in an environment such as

```
\newenvironment{alttheorem}
{%
 \addtocounter{theorem}{-1}%
 \renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{theorem}'}%
 \theorem}
{\endtheorem}
```

then use an `alttheorem` environment after a `theorem` one.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would there be any way to incorporate this into a newly defined environment?

Comment: yes sure (I'll put it in the answer as code formatting in comments is rubish)

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to use `\label`, `\ref` just in case the restated theorem is not exactly after the original one?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It might be although it's a bit harder as by default `\ref` doesn't necessarily return something locally reusable as `\thetheorem` (and if you poke at `\ref` internals you have to be careful not to trip over `hyperref` which changes them)